# Why does the word 'Well-to-do' mean 'rich'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

How has the expression  '[well to do](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/well-to-do)' developed the connotation of being  'rich'?

Does anyone  know the origin of this expression, which accoring to Merrian Webster, dates back  to 1794, while [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/well) dates its usage from  1825.

> Well-to-do "prosperous" is recorded from 1825.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it's always had that meaning. What do you mean by "developed"?

Comment: @won suk J daily142857, Before 'developing' to the connotation of being 'rich', had it had another meaning?

Comment: Perhaps helpful to develop an understanding of "well-to-do": In German, there is a similar phrase "Ihm geht es gut" (him-goes-it-well); this can be used for everything from health over finances to general happyness.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann, that is helpful, but, on the other hand, it also makes it that much more puzzling why in English the phrase is idiomatically used *only* for financial well-being, and *not* for health, etc., which is what the OP is, I guess, wondering about.

Comment: Also germane is the question of the rather strange grammatical structure of "well-to-do". Could it be a rather literal translation from another language? "Well-to-do" doesn't seem to relate to any other English phrase. For example, we can't vary the adverb and say, "He is ill-to-do" meaning poor; or "He is slowly-to-learn" (though we can say "He is slow [adjective] to learn"); and we can't change the final verb and say "He is well-to-write".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression "well-to-do" has always meant rich. The 1794 use of this expression is:

> Ann Low told me that her mother lived in the country, and was very well to do.
>   <sub>[Old Bailey Proceedings.](https://www.oldbaileyonline.org/browse.jsp?name=17940716)</sub>

Etymonline uses the Oxford English Dictionary as its source. The [1825 date](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ohw4AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA230&lpg=PA230&dq="Weel-te-dee,+well+to+do%E2%80%94living+comfortably".) comes from OED2. It wasn't until 2014 that the page was updated (OED3), adding the 1794 quote (among others).

It's also worth noting two earlier expressions that also mean rich:

- Well to live (earliest attestation: [1568](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A01584.0001.001?rgn=main;view=fulltext))
- Well to pass (earliest attestation: [1609](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/e/eebo/A09744.0001.001/1:29?rgn=div1;view=fulltext))

"Well to pass" comes at least in part from Dutch *wel te pas* (Middle Dutch *wel te passe*).

Comment: To Laurel: that's a useful answer, thank you. What are the sources for "well to live" and "well to pass"?

Comment: @StephenF The attestation dates of both come from the subscription only online OED, from the sources I have just edited to add.

Comment: Thank you, Laurel.